# Ionic2 - adding extern Service - "Uncaught Invalid provider"

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, provider

I want to create an Angular2 library that I can use in Angular2-Projects or Ionic2-Projects

I wrote the following service:

```
//libraryTester.ts    
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LibraryTester {
   constructor() {} 
}
```

After that I tried to include it in my Ionic2 Project by adding the Import

```
//app.ts

import { LibraryTester } from "absolutePathTo_libraryTester";
```

and the import to the import to ionicBootstrap

```
//app.ts
ionicBootstrap(
    MyAppComponent,[LibraryTester]
);
```

Without using it in any component I alway get the following error in the console (the typescript-compiler gives me no error..):

> Uncaught Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are
>   allowed, got: undefined

There are some similar questions here in stack overflow, but nothing could help me to fix it.

Comment: you are importing it wrongly. import with code : `import { LibraryTester } from "absolutePathTo_libraryTester";`

Comment: @ranakrunal9 .. thx, but i just made a c&p failure. I have it like you wrote..

Comment: Ionic 2 have a build system.. `.ts` files doesnt need an absolute path.. try `import { LibraryTester } from "./relative/path/libraryTester"`